# Programming a servo on an ATtiny85

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, attiny85

Board: "ATtiny25/45/85"

Processor: "ATtiny85"

Clock: "Internal 1 MHz"

Programmer: "Arduino as ISP"

I want to run a servo forwards and backwards on an ATtiny85. The servo library is not compatible with the ATtiny85 so I had to write code from scratch. At this point, the code that makes the servo go forwards (clockwise) is:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(PB1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PB1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  // 1 millisecond determines the servo going forwards
  digitalWrite(PB1, LOW);
  delay(19);
}
```

And the code that makes the servo go backwards (anti-clockwise) is simply by changing the amount of microseconds to:

```
delayMicroseconds(2000);
```

I want to have the servo motor go forwards one cycle for a few seconds and then go backwards for a few. I want this to keep looping. At this point my code is:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(PB1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PB1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  digitalWrite(PB1, LOW);
  delay(19);
  digitalWrite(PB1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
  digitalWrite(PB1, LOW);
  delay(19);
}
```

This however just makes the servo go back and forward at the same spot forever. I do realise I might need a for loop for this but I am confused as how I will do this.

Comment: Did you have a try on using **8MHz**.

Comment: @AllenChak yeah I did try that however, that still doesn't produce the output that i want because I want the servo to spin forwards and backwards in a row rather than separately.

Comment: Try this link: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=62912.msg459183#msg459183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servo can't move back and forward in 40 milliseconds. It'll be more like tremble between both.

Try something like this:

```
// keep sending 0 position for about 400ms
for(int i = 0; i<20; ++i) {
  digitalWrite(PB1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  digitalWrite(PB1, LOW);
  delay(19);
}

// keep sending second position for about 400ms
for(int i = 0; i<20; ++i) {
  digitalWrite(PB1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2000);
  digitalWrite(PB1, LOW);
  delay(18);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot it really helped and it makes sense too. I just have one question, that delay(19) when changed to delay(20) the servo behaves differently. Why is that delay kept at 19 milliseconds and not something else? thanks again.

Comment: The servo expects pulses at 20ms rate (= 50Hz) including High side pulse width.

Comment: In trying to find basic code to work a servo, this helped a lot. Thank you!